# extjs treenode appendchild not working correctly

Tags: extjs

I have a treepanel which is loaded on demand from a web rest api. The rest api will return an array with the data according to the id of the selected node. Here is the code:

```
itemdblclick: function(item, record, eOpts) {
        var store = Ext.getStore('mystore');
        var newStore = Ext.create('mystore', {
            autoDestroy: true,
            storeId: 'otherId'
        });
        var parentid = record.data.id;
        var that = this;

    newStore.proxy.extraParams = {...};
    newStore.autoDestroy = true;
    newStore.storeId = 'otherId';

    newStore.load({
        callback: function(items) {
            var node = store.getRootNode().findChild('id', record.data.idelement, true);

            for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
                var item = items[i].data;
                var child = {..., idparent: parentid};
                var newnode = node.createNode(child);
                node.appendChild(newnode, true);
            }
            node.expand();
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks to [norbeq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4340950/norbeq) who gave me the light to change the id of the second store. The thing is the tree is nicely populated and the node is expanded, but (why there is always a but?) next the expanded node there is no a `-`, the `+` remains the same.

This is what I mean:

[image: screenshot 1]

I've sourrounded in red that the `+` mark remains and that the folder is still closed.

Also, if I click the `+` symbol this is what happend:

[image: screenshot 2]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I have to say that the official extjs documentation is quite poor for me. I found a solution by test and reading a lot of posts in several foros. I found a solution that might be helpful to others:

```
var rootNode = store.getRootNode();

                for (var i = 0, l = records.length; i < l; i++) {
                    var x = records[i].data;
                    var child = { ... };

                    if (!child.idparent) {
                        rootNode.appendChild(child);
                    } else {
                        var parent = rootNode.findChild('idelement', child.idparent, true);
                        parent.appendChild(child);
                    }

                    if (!child.leaf) {
                        var node = store.findNode('idelement', child.idelement);
                        node.set('expanded', true);
                    }
                }

                rootNode.set('expanded', true);
```

That's it